# Disable Origin SSL Protocols TLSv1 in CloudFront/ALB

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, https, configuration, amazon-cloudfront

I would like to disable the TLSv1 in cloudFront and I already un-tick it on the Origin SSL Protocols setting. but don't know why it still enforced.Already do the SSL offload setting.

Structure : CloudFront -> ALB -> GROUP(instances)

Am i missing any step/setting?

Thanks

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Apps Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) or [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.